# Is the Solr equivalent of Sitecore.Social.Lucene.Index.Analytics.Facebook.config needed when switching from Lucene to Solr?

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm in the process of migrating indexes from Lucene to Solr for a Sitecore site on Sitecore 8.2 Update 2 (Sitecore 8.2 rev. 161221). I'm disabling the Lucene specific configs and enabling the Solr specific versions of those indexes. This went fine for most of the indexes but there is no Solr specific configuration in the vanilla Sitecore 8.2 install for **Sitecore.Social.Lucene.Index.Analytics.Facebook.config**.

```
 <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
<index id="sitecore_analytics_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
        <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
        <param desc="folder">$(id)</param>
        <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
        <param desc="group">experience</param>
        <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration">
          <fieldMap ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration/fieldMap">
            <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
              <field fieldName="contact.social.facebook.id"    storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS" boost="1f" emptyString="_EMPTY_" nullValue="_NULL_" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              </field>
              <field fieldName="contact.social.facebook.appid" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS" boost="1f" emptyString="_EMPTY_" nullValue="_NULL_" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              </field>
            </fieldNames>               
          </fieldMap>
        </configuration>
      </index>
  </indexes>
```

Is this because Solr doesn't need these additional fields in the `sitecore_analytics_index`? Part of the analytics index is defined in `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Analytics.config` but the index doesn't show up in Indexing manager so I can't manually rebuild it to see if it works.

Do I need to create a Solr version for this file or is it only required for Lucene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issue and I add new config for solr and it works fine 
This is the content of the config file : **Sitecore.Social.Solr.Index.Analytics.Facebook.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
   <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
     <configuration>
      <indexes>
       <index id="sitecore_analytics_index">
        <configuration>
          <fieldMap>
            <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
              <field fieldName="contact.social.facebook.id" returnType="string"/>
              <field fieldName="contact.social.facebook.appid" returnType="string"/>
            </fieldNames>
          </fieldMap>
        </configuration>
      </index>
    </indexes>
  </configuration>
</contentSearch>
```

Comment: Good to know. I'll add the Solr version also just to cover the bases

Comment: Should it show up in the indexing manager once you do this?

Comment: Analytics_index is not shown in the indexing manager. Is not recommended to index manually